# Can't install CS50 library on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: cs50

Trying to install the library in my Ubuntu 17.04 machine and also with some other machines with Ubuntu 17.4 but seems like in not yet supported because I'm always facing the following problem

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/cs50/ppa/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cs50/ppa/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
```

which cause this problem `E: Unable to locate package libcs50` when attempting to install it using `sudo apt-get install libcs50` as mensioned in the REDME file.

Anyone faced the same problem and solved it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of downvote the question, comment with what's wrong with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for helping people who faced the same problem : 
I Opened an issues in the GitHub repository and they fixed it : Just follow the instructions in the README.